# Magento 1.9 how to remain products after customer logout also in cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to keep products in cart after customer logout also.

```
<events>
    <customer_logout>
        <observers>
            <pengo_customer_logout_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Pengo_Customer_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>preserveQuote</method>
            </pengo_customer_logout_observer>
        </observers>
    </customer_logout>
</events>

public function preserveQuote(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customerQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($observer->getCustomer());
    $currentQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $currentQuote->merge($customerQuote);
}
```

Comment: I may be off-base, but couldn't this be accomplished with system settings for [Persistent Shopping Cart](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/sales/shopping-cart-persistent.html)?